# Maple combstruct

Tags: generating-functions, maple

How do I implement pointing in Maple with combstruct?

I'm writing a symbolic generating function and I need to do something along the lines of A = Point(B) where Point would be a pointing operation, but I don't think combstruct has such a operation; if so, would there be a way to replicate pointing using combstruct?

Comment: Combstruct is a remarkable achievement of combinatorics software. I suggest you look at the original combstruct tech reports (which I do not have memorized at this time). I believe they treat pointing. When doing labeled enumeration you can just differentiate the EGF and multiply by the main variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undocumented constructor `` `combstruct/Theta` `` which can be used to signify pointing.  It is the reification of $x \frac{d}{dx}$ to the level of grammars.  It is not fully supported, but worked in the examples I tried.